# Method range of object worksheet failed

Tags: vba

I keep getting this error an searched for a solution, but couldn't find it. 
Can anyone point out what is wrong with below code?

```
    Sub test()
    Dim WKB As ThisWorkbook
    Set WKB = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim DataPivotSheet As Worksheet
    Set DataPivotSheet = WKB.Sheets("DataPivot")
    Dim YTDDataTableSheet As Worksheet
    Set YTDDataTableSheet = WKB.Sheets("YTD Data Table")
    Dim Startrow As Long

    If YTDDataTableSheet.Cells(2, 1) = False Then
    Startrow = YTDDataTableSheet.Cells(2, 1).Row
    Else: Startrow = YTDDataTableSheet.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Row
    End If

    YTDDataTableSheet.Cells(2, 22) = Startrow

    'Below line gets the error:
    DataPivotSheet.Range("J3", Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Copy 
    Destination:=YTDDataTableSheet.Range("A" & Startrow)

    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a line continuation on that line?  The `Destination` is part of the same line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Common problem in Excel-VBA: You haven't qualified the `Range("A3")`. Although it seems obvious you want to access a range from `DataPivotSheet`, Excel doesn't do so if you don't tell. Instead, it will use a Range from the *active* workbook which is probably not `DataPivotSheet`.

You can write

```
DataPivotSheet.Range("J3", DataPivotSheet.Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Copy _
    Destination:=YTDDataTableSheet.Range("A" & Startrow)
```

or, maybe better to read (note the dot before the `Range`)

```
With DataPivotSheet
    .Range("J3", .Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Copy _
        Destination:=YTDDataTableSheet.Range("A" & Startrow)
End With
```

or, to split your rather complicated `copy`-statement (makes is easier to debug)

```
With DataPivotSheet
    Dim endCell As Range
    Set endCell = .Range("A3").End(xlDown)
    .Range("J3", endCell).Copy Destination:=YTDDataTableSheet.Range("A" & Startrow)
End With
```

**As a rule of thumb**: Never access `Range` without a `dot`. Even *if* you want to access a range from `ActiveSheet` (and you will not want this very often), it's better to write `ActiveSheet.Range`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. really helps allot also for writing future code.

Answer (score 0):

`Range("A3").End(xlDown)` will return a reference to a cell itself and not the address property of the cell.
As you do not specify the sheet with that range it will also look at the `ActiveSheet`.  If that isn't the `DataPivot` sheet then it will be trying to create a reference from cells on different sheets.

You could use:

```
DataPivotSheet.Range("J3", Range("A3").End(xlDown).Address).Copy _
        Destination:=YTDDataTableSheet.Range("A" & Startrow)
```

Or

```
With DataPivotSheet
    .Range(.Range("J3"), .Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Copy _
        Destination:=YTDDataTableSheet.Range("A" & Startrow)
End With
```

On a side note working from the bottom up is often a better way to find the last row:

```
YTDDataTableSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```